# MATLAB - build a graph without knowing the actual value of x

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I have the following task to be completed in Matlab:

build graphic of the following function

```
x+sin(3x)/(x^2+1)
```

How can I build a graph without knowing the actual value of **x**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ezplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) to do this:

```
ezplot('x+sin(3.*x)/(x^2+1)')
```

[image]